# Discoverment of new devices in Kaa

Tags: kaa

I am using Kaa for a Smart Farming  and I would like to know if a automatic discoverment of new devices is allowed in Kaa and if the platform detects when a node connection has failed.

Answer (score 0):

The Kaa SDK provides meaning of an endpoint which is almost the same as the device in your case. A new endpoint can be pre-provisioned with its credentials or not (depending on the security schema used) prior to its first connection to Kaa server.

The Kaa server does not discover any (new) enpoints. Instead, an endpoint should establish a connection to the Kaa server, provide its credentials and identity information. Then, the Kaa server may authenticate the endpoint, persist its metadata and provide connectivity status information.

See [Kaa REST API documentation](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Server-REST-APIs/) for more information.